# How to get `count(*)/sum(Duration)` in elasticsearch(5.1.1) using curl?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, kibana-5

I want to use two aggregates at a time my curl command should return the output based on this expression `count(*)/sum(Duration)` how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

curl 'localhost:9200/consumer/_search?q=*&pretty'

The above curl query(considering the index name is consumer) returns paginated list of all the records. Check the "total" under "hits" to find the total number of records.

Comment: I want to divide the total count with sum of duration